# Django in Docker - Entrypoint to initiate Django App Files

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, persistence

at the moment I am trying to build a Django App, that other users should be able to use as Docker-Container. I want them to easily do a run command or starting a prewritten docker-compose file to start the container.

Now, I have problems with the persistence of the data. I am using the volume flag in docker-compose for example to bind mount a local folder of the host into the container, where the app data and config files are located on the container. The host folder is empty on the first run, as the user just installed docker and is just starting the docker-compose.

As it is a bind mount, the empty folder overrides the folder in Docker as far as I understood and so the Container-Folder, containing the Django-App is now empty and so it is not startable.

I searched a bit and as far as I understood, I need to create a entrypoint.sh file that copies  the app data folder into the folder of the container after the startup, where the volume is.

Now to my questions:

1. Is there a Best Practice of how to copy the files via an entrypoint.sh file?
2. What about a second run, after 1. worked and files already exist, how to not override the maybe changed config files with the default ones in the temp folder?

My example code for now:

**Dockerfile**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.6

# set work directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app


# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# copy project
COPY . /app/

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#one of my tries to make data persistent
VOLUME /app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
    volumes:
        - /folder/to/app/data:/app
    networks:
      - overlay-core
networks:
    overlay-core:
      external: true
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#empty for now
```

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure your application to store the application code and its data in different directories.  Even if the data is a subdirectory of the application, that's good enough.  Once you do that, you can bind-mount only the data directory and leave the application code from the image intact.

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data # not /app
```

There's no particular reason to put a `VOLUME` declaration in your Dockerfile, but you should declare the `CMD` your image should run there.

Comment: Thanks David, will look into it. And if I have it setup with a data folder, how to copy the files in data onto the host, so the user can access it?